# TextArea autoscroll to bottom on Vaadin UI

Tags: javascript, user-interface, textarea, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a Polymer Template view which includes a TextArea on a Vaadin 14 frontend. To this view I have the corresponding Java companion file. The content of my text area is being appended each time an action/event occurs, so technically it is functioning as a console. When this text area has a certain amount of lines, the scrolling bar shows up, but adding new values to the text area results in representing the top values still. Is it possible somehow to autoscroll to the bottom of the text area each time its value is changed? I've checked out some solutions that was only for previous versions of Vaadin, not for flow. Can this be done using the Java API or there should be some css/javaScript workaround used?

What I tried for scrolling so far without success:

```
 Page page = UI.getCurrent().getPage();

 page.executeJs("document.getElementById('myTextAreaId').scrollTop =  
          document.getElementById('myTextAreaId').scrollHeight",
          myTextArea.getElement());
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your logic, where on some event a new value is appended to a textarea. I've defined an `updateScrollPosition` JS method inside the template to update the `scrollTop` property each time a new value is appended to a TextArea. The method contains :

```js
let textAreaElement = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("vaadin-text-area").shadowRoot.querySelector("div[part='input-field']");

textAreaElement.scrollTop = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
```

I am using for simplicity the maximum integer, as by the [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) it sets scrollTop to the maximum value.

When a textarea value changes you would need to call the defined function using `getElement().callJsFunction("updateScrollPosition");`

Overall, my template looks like this :

```js
import {html, PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-text-field/src/vaadin-text-area.js';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-button/src/vaadin-button.js';

class TextareaComponent extends PolymerElement {

    static get template() {
        return html`
<style include="shared-styles">
                :host {
                    display: block;
                    height: 100%;
                }
            </style>
<vaadin-text-area label="Write a description" placeholder="Add detailed explanation" id="textareaId"></vaadin-text-area>
<vaadin-button id="buttonID">
 Add text 
</vaadin-button>
`;
    }
    updateScrollPosition(){
        let textAreaElement = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("vaadin-text-area").shadowRoot.querySelector("div[part='input-field']");
        textAreaElement.scrollTop = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
    }

    static get is() {
        return 'textarea-component';
    }

    static get properties() {
        return {
            // Declare your properties here.
        };
    }
}

customElements.define(TextareaComponent.is, TextareaComponent);
```

and the `java` counterpart like this

```java
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.Id;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextArea;
import com.vaadin.flow.templatemodel.TemplateModel;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Tag;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.JsModule;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.PolymerTemplate;

/**
 * A Designer generated component for the textarea-component template.
 *
 * Designer will add and remove fields with @Id mappings but
 * does not overwrite or otherwise change this file.
 */
@Tag("textarea-component")
@JsModule("./src/textarea-component.js")
public class TextareaComponent extends PolymerTemplate<TextareaComponent.TextareaComponentModel> {

    @Id("textareaId")
    TextArea area;

    @Id("buttonID")
    Button button;

    /**
     * Creates a new TextareaComponent.
     */
    public TextareaComponent() {
        // You can initialise any data required for the connected UI components here.
        area.setMaxHeight("150px");
        button.addClickListener(event -> {
           area.setValue(area.getValue() + " New button click!");
           // this is important line
           getElement().callJsFunction("updateScrollPosition");
        });
    }

    /**
     * This model binds properties between TextareaComponent and textarea-component
     */
    public interface TextareaComponentModel extends TemplateModel {
        // Add setters and getters for template properties here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works as expected. For some reason callJsFunction() is not working at all (tried even with a plain alert() ) so I had to use executeJs() with the whole function body provided as string argument. Its deprecated but did the job finally:)